# ErrorIrresolvableConflict while trying update a mail resource

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using the Graph API in order to update a mail resource - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http 
It usually works, but we had an error code that we never seen before: ErrorIrresolvableConflict here is the full error message: "The send or update operation could not be performed because the change key passed in the request does not match the current change key for the item." 
Can you please help us to understand what this error means and how can we recover from such situations? 
Thanks